# Ist ein Satz der Art "..., oder?" grammatikalisch falsch?

Tags: word-usage

Ich hatte gestern abend eine Diskussion darüber, ob ein Satz der Art "..., oder?" gültig oder falsch ist.

Konkretes Beispiel:

> Du kommst auch mit, oder?

Comment: Warum sollte der Satz falsch sein?

Comment: Die Person mit der ich gestern sprach behauptete das. Mich hat es verwirrt und da ich im Internet nichts finden konnte hab ich die Frage hier gestellt.

Comment: Sätze mit _...oder?_ hört man oft in der Schweiz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Satz ist gültig, ist einfach eine Kurzform von

> Du kommst auch mit, oder [etwa] nicht?

oder auch von

> Du kommst auch mit, oder hast du es dir [etwa] anders überlegt?
>   Du kommst auch mit, oder spricht etwas dagegen?

oder von weiteren Konstruktionen dieser Art.

Comment: Mich würde an dieser Stelle brennend interessieren, ob das Komme optional ist.

Comment: Das Komma ist obligatorisch.